# PBI Measure as a Value in Matrix Visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I appreciate some help with the below problem.
I have the table

| Month | Line | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | ST | 20 |
| Jan | AB | 10 |
| Jan | AC | 2 |
| Jan | AG | 15 |
| Feb | ST | 40 |
| Feb | AB | 20 |
| Feb | AC | 4 |
| Feb | AG | 8 |
| Mar | ST | 65 |
| Mar | AB | 5 |
| Mar | AC | 6 |
| Mar | AG | 2 |

and I want a Matrix

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 50.00% | 50.00% | 7.69% |
| AC | 10.00% | 10.00% | 9.23% |
| AG | 75.00% | 20.00% | 3.08% |

The Value of the Matrix is a Mesure

```
(%) Amount ST =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AB",
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( table1[Amount] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), FILTER ( 'table1', table1[Line] = "ST" ) )
        ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AC",
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( table1[Amount] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), FILTER ( 'table1', table1[Line] = "ST" ) )
        ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AG", DIVIDE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), 4 ),
    SUM ( table1[Amount] )
)
```

The measure works fine for AG, to test it I used in the denominator the number 4, but when I added the calculate function to filter by ST I didn't see it in the visual ???

Any ideas

Thank you
OJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you calculating. From your measure, is this is what are you looking for?

### DAX Calculation

```
(%) Amount ST = 
VAR STAmount =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), table1[Line] = "ST" )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AB", DIVIDE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), STAmount ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AC", DIVIDE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), STAmount ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( table1[Line] ) = "AG", DIVIDE ( SUM ( table1[Amount] ), STAmount ),
        SUM ( table1[Amount] )
    )
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Angelo Canepa Thank you so much,  yes that is what I want I will try it and come here to reply with the result ...

Comment: I tried the same error,  the matrix only shows ST everything that is divided by STAmount doesn't appear... seems the filter by ST in Calculate function doesn't allow the other values to show up ????

Comment: Angelo Canepa yes, your Dax works with the data that I gave ... strange in my real example doesn't work ...

Comment: Thank you Angelo I created a new report with only the table and worked so is something related to my other DAX or Visual you answered my question I will close the case 
Thank you

Comment: Hi @ofeliajesus, if the answer was helpful please mark it as a solution.